# can't execute class library in mono develop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I created a C# class library using visual studio and it works well in visual studio, and when trying to execute it in  mono develop I get error 
the library code:

```
    namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class2
    {

      public  static void dosomething() {Console.WriteLine("dfss"); }
    }
}
```

the code in mono develop:

```
namespace cons
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            ClassLibrary2.Class2.dosomething();
        }
    }
}
```

the error 
[image: the error]

Comment: The exception mentions a `ClassLibrary2`, your code doesn't. Something doesn't fit together here.

Comment: it's a typing error sorry it was class library 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What target framework (2.0, 3.5, 4.0) did you specify in VS?? It seems that your mono develop uses different (lower) version.

Comment: @Amged : well, the latest version should be able to cope with almost everythin in .NET 4.0. Maybe you need to update you mono installation?

Comment: @Amged: seems to be up to date. Have you used the Mono Migration Analyzer (http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) on your libs assembly, it may give you more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that your .Net Framework versions are the same. You will have chosen a framework in VS that is different to that which mono develop is trying to use. This is a very common cause of this error.

Comment: Probably right. The error explicitly mentions "The assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime". You need to specify a target version that's compatible with the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The missing assembly is **ClassLibrary2** and your code only deals with **ClassLibrary1**.

Maybe you could add the registry key to enable a more verbose logging.

Comment: it was just class library 2 in all codes there is no class library 1, I'm sorry it's typing error